# Android: Displaying contact names in a Spinner

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to simply get contacts from the Device phone book and display them on a Spinner, the code:

```
    // Form an array specifying which columns to return. 
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
        People._ID, People.NAME
    };

    // Get the base URI for the People table in the Contacts content provider.
    Uri contacts =  People.CONTENT_URI;

    Spinner contactsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.recipient_names);

    // Make the query.
    Cursor contactsCursor = managedQuery(contacts,
                             PROJECTION, // Which columns to return 
                             null,       // Which rows to return (all rows)
                             null,       // Selection arguments (none)
                             // Put the results in ascending order by name
                             People.NAME + " ASC");

    Log.e("EE", String.valueOf(contactsCursor.getCount()));

    SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        contactsCursor, new String[] {People.NAME}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1}
    );

    Log.e("EE", String.valueOf(sca.getCount()));

    sca.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    contactsSpinner.setAdapter(sca);
```

Compiles and runs fine, just that... The logs is showing 1 for both Log.e() call, which I think imply that contacts were actually retrieved successfully, however the Spinner is empty... Could anyone tell me I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it's not supported on sdk > 2.0